# Dynamically populate dropdown inside spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx-webparts

I am new to spfx webpart. I have following clarification.

Is it possible to populate choice column values of a library to drop down control dynamically.

Note: I don't want to display dropdown as webpart property.

Dropdown is a control inside webpart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code:

```
const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
  dropdown: { width: 300 }
};
const options: IDropdownOption[] = [  
  { key: 'apple', text: 'Apple' },
  { key: 'banana', text: 'Banana' },
  { key: 'orange', text: 'Orange'},
  { key: 'grape', text: 'Grape' },
  { key: 'broccoli', text: 'Broccoli' },
  { key: 'carrot', text: 'Carrot' },
  { key: 'lettuce', text: 'Lettuce' }
];
const stackTokens: IStackTokens = { childrenGap: 20 };
```

Add below stack tag inside render return function

```
<Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
      <Dropdown placeholder="Select an option" label="Basic uncontrolled example" options={options} styles={dropdownStyles} />
    </Stack>
```

Above code with static JSON Data:

**Now dynamically add the dropdown list using the SharePoint list data:**

```
var items: IDropdownOption[]=[];

export interface IReactGetItemsState{ 
  items: IDropdownOption[];
}
```

Then add then below constructor inside the class method to initialise the state

```
public constructor(props: ISpfxReactReadProps, state: IReactGetItemsState){ 
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
      items: []
    }; 
  }
```

Add the below ‘componentDidMount()’ method just below the constructor method. This method retrieves SharePoint list items using pnp sp js and sets it in the state using ‘setState’

```
public async componentDidMount(): Promise<void>
  {
    // get all the items from a sharepoint list
    var reacthandler=this;
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Projects").items.select('Title').get().then(function(data){
      for(var k in data){
        items.push({key:data[k].Title, text:data[k].Title});
      }
      reacthandler.setState({items});
      console.log(items);
      return items;
    });
  }
```

Example:
[image: Load dropdown list using the SharePoint list item in SPFx]

For details implementation refer to the below article:

[SPFX Load SharePoint list items in a dropdown using PNP SP JS](http://www.sharepointsamples.com/spfx-load-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-dropdown-using-pnp-sp-js/)

Comment: @Ropaesh: If the above answered helped you or answered your question - could you please mark as answered - so that it will help the upcoming visitors. Thanks for your understanding. :-)